# Preprocessor errors trying to build FVWM95

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Trying to build fvwm95-2.0.43f I get the following errors:

```
FvwmIconBox.c: In function 'myErrorHandler':
FvwmIconMan.c:412:1: error: pasting "." and "res" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

OS is Debian, tried Wheezy and Jessie. My best guess is that this might just be a minor change to how gcc handles preprocessor syntax since FVWM95 came out, but not sure.

Grab the source here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fvwm95/files/fvwm95/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, pasting the actual line and the preprocessor macro might have been useful, because we all love downloading tgz's that haven't seen changes in the last 12.5 years:

```
#define SET_MANAGER(manager,field,value)                           \
   do {                                                            \
     int id = manager;                                             \
     if (id == -1) {                                               \
       for (id = 0; id < globals.num_managers; id++) {             \
     globals.managers[id].##field = value;                     \
       }                                                           \
     }                                                             \
     else if (id < globals.num_managers) {                         \
       globals.managers[id].##field = value;                       \
     }                                                             \
     else {                                                        \
       ConsoleMessage ("Internal error in SET_MANAGER: %d\n", id); \
     }                                                             \
   } while (0)
```

L. 412:

```
SET_MANAGER (manager, res, r);
```

You're right: It's a "minor change" that happened suddenly in the last one eigth of a decade ;):

from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html :

> However, two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be
>   pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in
>   either order. If you try, the preprocessor issues a warning and emits
>   the two tokens. Whether it puts white space between the tokens is
>   undefined. It is common to find unnecessary uses of ‘##’ in complex
>   macros. If you get this warning, it is likely that you can simply
>   remove the ‘##’.

Comment: Sorry, I figured linking to the actual source was preferable!

Comment: Generally, I'd agree, but in this case, it's a bit of a hassle :) also, I kind of figured you already had a look at the macro and the line where it goes wrong yourself, so why not add this to your question? :)

Comment: now I'm totally curious why you'd need an ancient window manager?

Comment: The C standard says "If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined." (([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.10.3.3 paragraph 3.)

Comment: Removing the "##"s did the trick! Thank you! I want to run fvwm95 for several reasons. Novelty, nostalgia, an interest in retro computing, and as a learning experience. (to see if I can get it working, with help of course)

Comment: I don't know how much has changed in Xorg (formerly Xfree86), so I wish you the best of luck!